# Placing values from a joint table in a class in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to put a database result into a class but it won't let me probably because of an inner join. Please see my code below

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/getproperties")]
public List<Building> GetProperties()
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {

        var list = (from b in db.Buildings
                            join bi in db.BuildingImages on b.BuildingId equals bi.BuildingId
                            select new
                            {
                                b.AdvncPymtAnlScheme,
                                b.BuildingId,
                                b.BuildingName,
                                b.Cluster,
                                b.CollNoticesFreq,
                                b.DiscAmt,
                                b.DiscDeadline,
                                b.DiscDesc,
                                b.DuesRateAmt,
                                b.DuesRateUnit,
                                b.Fee,
                                b.FeeAssmtFreq,
                                b.FeeAssmtType,
                                b.FreqDuesAssmt,
                                b.InAssmType,
                                b.InAssmt,
                                b.InAssmtFreq,
                                b.LatePaymtPen,
                                b.PenHolday,
                                b.PenRate,
                                b.PenRateTerm,
                                b.ReaPropAssmtFreq,
                                b.RealPropAssmtType,
                                b.RealPropTxAssmt,
                                b.SoaDueDate,
                                b.SoaRelDate,
                                b.Type,
                                b.TypeOfAssmt,
                Maybe why ==>>  bi.ImageName
                            }).ToList();

        return list;

    }
}
```

**My Model**

```
[Table("Building")]
public class Building
{
    [Key]
    public int BuildingId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string BuildingName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Cluster { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string SoaRelDate { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string SoaDueDate { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string DuesRateAmt { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string DuesRateUnit { get; set; }
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string FreqDuesAssmt { get; set; }
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string TypeOfAssmt { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string LatePaymtPen { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string PenRate { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string PenRateTerm { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CollNoticesFreq { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string InAssmt { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string InAssmtFreq { get; set; }
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string InAssmType { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string RealPropTxAssmt { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ReaPropAssmtFreq { get; set; }
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string RealPropAssmtType { get; set; }
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Fee { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FeeAssmtFreq { get; set; }
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string FeeAssmtType { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string AdvncPymtAnlScheme { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string DiscAmt { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string DiscDesc { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string DiscDeadline { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string PenHolday { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

If I do not use the "select new..."and just choose "select b" I get it fine but the problem is I would not be able to get the "bi.ImageName" from the joint table. I get the error in the "return list " `Error 2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SosaPmisApi.Models.Building>'`

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: `it won't let me` - Can you clarify what you mean? What actually happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: show us the error.

Comment: Change `select new` to `select new Building` and assign the query results to the properties of `Building`

Comment: please see the Error I added. Thank you.

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden: If I place the new Building, I get red lines in all my select new.

Comment: `select b).ToList()` should be fine.

Comment: @SeM: If I just use "select b).ToList(), I will not be able to get the bi.ImageName which is in another table.

Comment: Aaaaaa, that's what you meant by saying that you are not be able to get it. Probably would be better if you return some object containing your building and building image objects (i.e. `new SomeObject { Building = b, BuildingImageName = bi.ImageName }`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an instance of `Building` instead of an anonymous class:

```
var list = (from b in db.Buildings
           join bi in db.BuildingImages on b.BuildingId equals bi.BuildingId
           select new Building
           {
               AdvncPymtAnlScheme = b.AdvncPymtAnlScheme,
               BuildingId = b.BuildingId,
               //etc.
               ImagePath = bi.ImageName
           }).ToList();
```

Note that you are using `Building` like a "regular" class, not like an entity. This is OK since POCOs are still normal classes and can be treated as such.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is what Peter van der Heijden meant.